# Fancybox loading behaviour

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I used custom title for Fancybox with custom navigation.
The problem is when I click next/prev default buttons than loading icon does not displaying but when I click my custom nav/prev button the loading icon is always displayng beetween images. Please look it here - http://livedemo07682.prestatrend.com/product.php?id_product=14
And here is the code:

```
function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    if(currentArray.length==1) {
        return '<div id="custom-title"><span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" id="fancybox_close"></a></span>' + (title && title.length ? '<b>' + title + '</b>' : '' ) + '</div>';
    } else {
        return '<div id="custom-title"><span><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.close();" id="fancybox_close"></a></span>' + (title && title.length ? '<b>' + title + '</b>' : '' ) + '<p><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.prev();" id="fancybox_prev"></a> <a href="javascript:;" onclick="$.fancybox.next();" id="fancybox_next"></a><span id="fancybox_indexes">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + '</span></p>' + '</div>';
    }
}

$('.thickbox').fancybox({
    'titlePosition' : 'inside',
    'titleFormat' : formatTitle,
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'transitionIn'  : 'fade',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'overlayColor' : 'white',
    'overlayOpacity' : 0.5,
    'padding' : 0,
    'speedIn' : 350,
    'speedOut' : 100
});
```

So could anybody help how not displaying this loading icon when clickin custom next/prev buttonы?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `$.fancybox.hideActivity()` method to `onclick` for each custom button so

for `prev` button, change this

```
onclick="$.fancybox.prev();"
```

to this

```
onclick="$.fancybox.prev(); $.fancybox.hideActivity();"
```

and for `next` button, change this

```
onclick="$.fancybox.next();"
```

to this

```
onclick="$.fancybox.next(); $.fancybox.hideActivity();"
```